# PHP loop for WordPress custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, for-loop, advanced-custom-fields

I have a section of a website that uses a lot of custom fields for images. I also have a slider that uses those fields so for every image there is a line of code using that custom field. I tried using a loop but something is not right as it doesn't get any of the fields then.

This is how it is right now:

```
<! -- Variables -->
<?php $image1 = get_field('img-1'); ?>
<?php $image2 = get_field('img-2'); ?>
<?php $image3 = get_field('img-3'); ?>
<?php $image4 = get_field('img-4'); ?>
<?php $image5 = get_field('img-5'); ?>
<?php $image6 = get_field('img-6'); ?>
<?php $image7 = get_field('img-7'); ?>
<?php $image8 = get_field('img-8'); ?>
<?php $image9 = get_field('img-9'); ?>
<?php $image10 = get_field('img-10'); ?>

<!-- Slider -->
<div id="slider-constructora" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides"> <?php if( $image1 ): ?>
            <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo 

            <?php if( $image1 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image1['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $image2 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image2['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $image3 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image3['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $image4 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image4['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $image5 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image5['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $image6 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image6['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $image7 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image7['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $image8 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image8['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $image9 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image9['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $image10 ): ?>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image10['url']; ?>"></li>
            <?php endif; ?>

    </ul>
</div><!-- slider -->
```

This is what I have tried to use inside of the slider without success, I use it on another website and it does work, but not in this case:

```
<?php 
for( $iteration = 1; $iteration <= 150; $iteration++){ 

    if ( get_field("image".$iteration ) ){ ?>
        <li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo get_field("image".$iteration)['url'] ?>"></li>
    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You might find ACF's *'repeater'* field useful here, which can allow you/your users to add a dynamic number of images. It will also make it easier for you to loop the images (you won't need a `for` loop to iterate an arbitrary number of times).

Comment: That's a paid addition.

Comment: The repeater fields is definitely worth any penny you have to pay for it.

Comment: Sure it may be worth it but I'm just asking how to have this php loop to work for my code which works on another website.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error.  Note this part of the code:

```
<li><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo 

<?php if( $image1 ): ?>
```

You did not finish your `echo` or close your PHP tag before opening a new PHP tag and starting an IF statement. This will throw a fatal error.

I suggest enabling `WP_DEBUG` so that it is easier to catch these types of errors. To do this change or add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` so that it is `true`. [Debugging in WordPress (Codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)